# howto link an Arduino Light Sensor to a keyboard button?

Tags: java, arduino

I have an Arduino Uno and a light sensor. I would like the light sensor to activate the [H] button on my keyboard. If the light sensor is in the dark (1024) it should have the same effect as holding the [H] button until there is light again. How do I go about this?

Comment: Rogier, you might want to try your luck here as well: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/, which already has 400+ Arduino questions.

Comment: Electronics SE would be a great place to ask this, sorry that it had to be closed.